# How to tell which application has pushed a notification

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications

Android allows notifications to be pushed and some times when we install certain applications, they push adverts to the notification bar.

For example, this screen shot shows a notification icon that a download is in progress (and the notification is also shown in more detail when we expand the notification area).

[image]

My question is, how do we find out what posted any given notification. You can probably guess that I'm getting unwanted notifications (adverts/spam).

The advice is usually start uninstalling apps, reset the OS etc and whilst I don't disagree that those methods don't work, they're not easy either.

So, is it possible on stock Android 5 or higher to find out what application sent the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just long-press the notification. That should either directly lead to the corresponding app in *Settings › Apps* – or at least reveal a button to go there:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>The `ⓘ` button brings you to the details, where you also can configure notifications for that app (Android 5.1 here)</sup>

AFAIR that feature was added somewhere around Kitkat (Android 4.4), but not before JellyBean (4.2), so it should definitely be available with Android 5 (Lollipop).